# Why does adding a closure capture list prevent my instance from being deallocated?

Tags: swift, closures, reference-cycle

```
class Name {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    deinit {
        print("\(name) deinit")
    }
}
var x: Name? = Name(name: "abc")

var someClosure = {
    print("\(x?.name)")
}

someClosure()

x = nil
```

And then the console will output:

```
Optional("abc")
abc deinit
```

It can be seen that the "deinit" function was called. So it does not form a strong reference cycle.
But if I add a capture list to the closure:

```
var someClosure = { [x] in
    print("\(x?.name)")
}
```

The console will output:

```
Optional("abc")
```

And the "deinit" function was not called. So the object and reference form a strong reference cycle.

What is the reason? What's the difference between these two conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no strong retain *cycle* in either case – you just simply have a global closure variable that's holding a strong reference to your class instance, therefore preventing it from being deallocated.

In your first example, when you capture `x` in the closure:

```
var someClosure = {
    print("\(x?.name)")
}
```

What you've got (in effect) is a reference to a reference – that is, the closure has a reference to the storage of `x`, which then has a reference to your class instance. When you set `x` to `nil` – the closure still has a reference to the storage of `x`, but now `x` *doesn't* have a reference to your class instance. Thus, your class instance no longer has any strong references to it, and can be deallocated.

In your second example when you use a [capture list](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/superclass-method-expression):

```
var someClosure = { [x] in
    print("\(x?.name)")
}
```

You're *copying* `x` itself – that is, you're copying a reference to the instance of your class. Therefore the closure will keep your class retained as long as it exists. Setting `x` to `nil` doesn't affect the closure's reference to your instance, as it has it's *own* strong reference to it.

Comment: I have known your answer and am in favor of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think happens here.

ARC adds a reference count to `x` when `x` is created. When the closure is called with a capture list, it then adds another count (closure *captures* the object: thus indicating to the compiler it will need `x` in the future, by increasing the reference count). So `x` now has ARC count of 2.

When you assign `x` to `nil` it reduces the reference count by 1. If the count is 0, or there are only weak references to the object, then the object is deinitialized. If the count is more than 0, and the references are strong, the object is retained.

Without explicitly passing the capture list to the closure it only weakly captures the object. ARC then decides it is safe to deinit the object once the closure is done with it. Passing the capture list indicates to ARC that the object might be needed for the closure to operate on at various multiple times, so a strong reference is made.

Put another call to `someClosure()` after `x = nil` and see what happens in both cases.

Comment: I think this comes very close. The problem is that the compiler does not release the closure itself. If you put the code into a `do { ... }` block then the closure and x will be deallocated..

Comment: Yep, seems very much so.

Comment: There are no weak references here ;)